# apt-get update returns Acquire (30: Read only file system) Error in Heroku

Tags: heroku

I want to update the package list in Heroku for that i am trying to execute the command called `apt-get update` to download the latest packages but it returns `E: List directory /var/lib/apt/lists/partial is missing. - Acquire (30: Read-only file system)`. I tried to found the root cause for it but i couldn't found the solution for heroku. Can any one help me on how to fix the above error in heroku.

This is my first question in stackoverflow and i'm new to heroku as well. Please forgive me if i did anything wrong while asking this question

Comment: Same issue for me. I also tried adding a `heroku-postbuild` script and got the same error. I'm guessing their build agents have a read only file system.